# How do I assign an env variable in a node js application?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I working through [this tutorial](https://github.com/tawn33y/whatsapp-cloud-api/blob/main/TUTORIAL.md) to create a WhatsApp chatbot.

In the tutorial, API keys are defined within index.js.

I would like to store the API keys in a .env file and use the dotenv package.

Here is an extract of the original version of index.js:

```
import { createBot } from 'whatsapp-cloud-api';
const { createBot } = require('whatsapp-cloud-api');

(async () => {
  try {
    // replace the values below
    const from = 'YOUR_WHATSAPP_PHONE_NUMBER_ID';
    const token = 'YOUR_TEMPORARY_OR_PERMANENT_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    const to = 'PHONE_NUMBER_OF_RECIPIENT';
    const webhookVerifyToken = 'YOUR_WEBHOOK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN';
```

I would like to replace the strings, such as 'YOUR_WHATSAPP_PHONE_NUMBER_ID', with a string defined in the .env file. For example, I tried:

```
const { createBot } = require('whatsapp-cloud-api');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

(async () => {
  try {
    const from = process.env.FROM;
    const token = process.env.TOKEN;
    const to = process.env.TO; 
    const webhookVerifyToken = process.env.WEBHOOKVerifyToken;
```

after defining a .env file in the root directory with:

```
const FROM = YOUR_WHATSAPP_PHONE_NUMBER_ID
const TOKEN = YOUR_TEMPORARY_OR_PERMANENT_ACCESS_TOKEN
const TO = PHONE_NUMBER_OF_RECIPIENT
const WEBHOOKVerifyToken = YOUR_WEBHOOK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN
```

I just get an error that suggests the env strings have not been assigned. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am new to javascript and node.js so the answer may be obvious.

Comment: `after defining a .env file in the root directory with:` This is not the correct syntax for a .env file. Its not supposed to be javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your .env file to:

```
FROM=YOUR_WHATSAPP_PHONE_NUMBER_ID
TOKEN=YOUR_TEMPORARY_OR_PERMANENT_ACCESS_TOKEN
TO=PHONE_NUMBER_OF_RECIPIENT
WEBHOOKVerifyToken=YOUR_WEBHOOK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN
```

more info: [documentation](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/)